# How to change button color dynamically in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to change my button color dynamically but not achieved can someone suggest help

```
   <a  class="button buttonaquacss button-mini button-aqua  text-right pull-right"  (click)='send(button,detail.profile_id)' #button  [ngStyle]="{'background-color':  color}"><span><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>{{detail.innerHTML}}</span></a>   




  if (detail.connection_status == '') {
                    detail.innerHTML = "connect";
                    this.color = "red";
                }




send(button, index): void {

    var str = localStorage.getItem('social');
    var loc = JSON.parse(str);
    var id = loc.profile_id;
    var formdata = { recieved_id: index, sent_id: id }

    this.color = 'blue';
    var headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.http.post('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/requests/sendrequest/', formdata, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                button.innerHTML = "Pending";
                button.disabled = true;
                this.color = "#127bdc";

            }
            else {
                button.innerHTML = "Unable to send request";
            }
        });


}
```

I am trying to change my button color dynamically but not achieved can someone suggest help

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage the `ngStyle` directive:

```
<a  class="button buttonaquacss button-mini button-aqua  text-right pull-right" 
    [ngStyle]="{'background-color':  color}">
  (...)
</a>
```

Comment: It should ;-) Could you add the content of your `send` method into your question? Thanks!

Comment: It does not change because you already set the static code here.  this.color = "#127bdc"; You should get it from somewhere and not set there.

Comment: Is the following block executed: `if (response.json().error_code == 0) { ... }`?

Comment: So that's the problem. Your button is always blue... Where does the block take place in your component: `if (detail.connection_status == '') { ... }`?

Comment: That comes with costructor and the condition is always true

Comment: So does your button change from red to blue when clicking on the button at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be using **ngStyle** ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle ) using directive like this

```
ng-style="{color: myColor}"
```

directing to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to solve this problem would be to have a conditional class that overrides the color using `[class.newColor]="errorThrown"` This holds true to the principle of separating your logic from your styling.